# Ubuntu can not display photos from smart phone

Tags: 14.10, mtp

Ubuntu 14.10 can NOT display pictures with new Samsung Note 4 connected.
The error message is: `Failed to open input stream for file`

[image: Error message]

Comment: Have you tried this with any previous version of Ubuntu? I am quite sure that this is a problem with either MTP protocol itself or with the android permissions and not with Ubuntu, because this does not work with Ubuntu 14.04 as well. You have to copy any file(not just images) from phone to computer to view it.

Comment: @RegisteredUser Could you please convert that to an answer so that schmucks like me who go around hunting for unanswered questions don't have to look at this one any more.  ;-)  (And I'll upvote if you drop me a note and it's a good one too!)

Comment: @Fabby I have written an answer. Do have a look at it.

Answer (score 3):

As given on [the Wikipedia page for the MTP protocol](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Media_Transfer_Protocol)

> The main purpose of this protocol is to **allow only the transfer of media files** and associated metadata to and from portable devices, one transfer function, in or out, at a time. It **does not support operations such as open, edit and modify**. A workaround is to copy to the hosting system for these operations and then copy back.

To open or work on the files from your phone, you *have* to copy the respective files to your computer and *then* open them.

I can confirm this from my own experience. Furthermore, make sure the device is not on lock screen when plugged in. The built in security will not let the device mount.

Comment: An edit *and* an upvote!  **;-)**

Answer (score 1):

Most Android phones have a Camera mode (mostly labelled PTP), and with that mode selected, photo previewing does work on Ubuntu.

[image: Android screenshot]

Comment: nice answer, probably should be the accepted one